# What's it called when you read a book with a particular focus and that focus is what you see and remember but other topics you forget?

Tags: reading

I sometimes read with a particular focus or goal and don"t remember the things outside of my focus/goal even though I've read them. What is this phenomena called?

For example, you can read a religious text focusing on one subject and not notice the symbolism, then switch focus to symbolism and the symbols come to light. Switch your focus to numerology then you begin to notice the numbers in the story. That is three different things literal, symbolic, numerologic, and this phenomena is not limited to those things but also topic switching changes what you see in a story.

Comment: Maybe tunnel vision?

Comment: Maybe, perhaps this phenomena hasn't been coined yet? I tend to skip over, pay less attention, and fail to notice things while reading or studying until I change my focus to those things. I'm going to add an example to the question to help clarify

Comment: Maybe it's called "Selective Reading" where you tend to put more weight on those words that match your focus? Similar to tunnel vision I suppose